# OpenCV C++ memory leak issue

Tags: c++, opencv, memory-leaks

Just see the below code snippet -

```
# include "opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp"
# include "iostream"
int main() {
    while (true) {
        cv::Mat* mat = new cv::Mat(2000, 2000, CV_8UC3);
        std::cout << "mat size" << mat->size() << std::endl;
        mat->release();
        std::cout << "mat size after" << mat->size() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Problem after running is - ram keep filling.
I have 48 gb of ram, which got filled in just some minutes as the loop runs.

If i am releasing the memory, then why it keeps acquiring my ram.

Comment: Why are using `new`? Just `cv::Mat mat(2000, 2000, CV_8UC3);` without `mat->release();` ought to be fine. Every `new` must be followed by a `delete` and there is none in your code. You rarely need to use `new`/`delete` directly in modern C++. If you think you need it, rethink it first.

Comment: yea got you.. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`cv::Mat`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html) object contains metadata (width, height etc.) and a pointer to the image data.

As you can see in the link, the [`cv::Mat::release`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#ae48d4913285518e2c21a3457017e716e) method frees the memory allocated for the `cv::Mat` data (assuming the ref-count is 0).
It does not free the memory for the `cv::Mat` object itself (i.e. the instance of the class containing the medadata and data pointer).

In your case the object is allocated on the heap using `new` and therfore should be freed with a corresponding `delete`.

However - it is not clear why you use `new` at all. You can have the `cv::Mat` on the stack as an automatic variable:

```
cv::Mat mat(2000, 2000, CV_8UC3);
```

This way it's destructor (and deallocation) will be called automatically at the end of the scope.

Note that you can still use `release` if you need to free the data pointed by the `cv::Mat` object manually. In your case above it is not needed because the destrcutor of `cv::Mat` will take care of it for you.

Comment: yes i understood it.. thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

The memory leak issue in my MFC application is avoided by delay loading dll in the following order.

opencv_core2413d.dll;opencv_highgui2413d.dll;opencv_world460d.dll